# Fill in multiple text fields at once in python selenium

Tags: python, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script that auto fills in a site. The only issue is it is slow and uses the basic code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH').send_keys('Bla Bla Bla')
```

I want to have a way to fill in multiple fields at the same time instead of it filling in one field and then the next.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Get all your web elements in a list.
Iterate through the list and just type into the fields. Something like this :

```
list =[ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4]

for element in list:
    element.send_keys('text')
```

If you want to send different text to each elements, you could use a dictionary with key value pairs for elements and their corresponding text.

```
my_dict = {ele1:'Hello', ele2: 'Again'}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I want it to fill multiple fields at the same time. So for example it could be filling in the name and post code simultaneously

Comment: You cannot use multiple send_keys() methods in a chain. So I don't think its possible using send_keys()

Comment: Yeah i was looking into using JS and then execute script. The send_keys() was just to show what i am currently using.